# How to request data sequentially in Cycle.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, cyclejs

I’m new to reactive programming and toying around with cycle.js, trying to implement who to follow box from [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754). But I understood that for proper implementation (and learning purposes) I don’t have one piece of data: full user name. I can get it by sequentially getting users and then full user data from server. In imperative style I would do something like this:

```
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users`)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(users => fetch(users[0].url))
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(/* ... work with data ... */)
```

But how do I do it in cycle?
I’m using fetch driver and trying something like this:

```
function main({ DOM, HTTP }) {
  const users = `https://api.github.com/users`;

  const refresh$ = DOM.select(`.refresh`).events(`click`)

  const response$ = getJSON({ key: `users` }, HTTP)

  const userUrl$ = response$
    .map(users => ({
      url: R.prop(`url`, R.head(users)),
      key: `user`,
    }))
    .startWith(null)

  const request$ = refresh$
    .startWith(`initial`)
    .map(_ => ({
      url: `${users}?since=${random(500)}`,
      key: `users`,
    }))
    .merge(userUrl$)

  const dom$ = ...

  return {
    DOM: dom$,
    HTTP: request$,
  };
}
```

where `getJSON` is

```
function getJSON(by, requests$) {
  const type = capitalize(firstKey(by));

  return requests$
    [`by${type}`](firstVal(by))
    .mergeAll()
    .flatMap(res => res.json());
```

And I’m always getting some cryptic (for me) error like: `TypeError: Already read`. What does it mean and how do I handle it properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were quite close. You just need to remove `startWith(null)` as a request, and grabbing the second response (you were missing the getJSON for that one).

```
function main({ DOM, HTTP }) {
  const usersAPIPath = `https://api.github.com/users`;

  const refresh$ = DOM.select(`.refresh`).events(`click`);

  const userResponse$ = getJSON({ key: `user` }, HTTP);
  const listResponse$ = getJSON({ key: `users` }, HTTP);

  const userRequest$ = listResponse$
    .map(users => ({
      url: R.prop(`url`, R.head(users)),
      key: `user`,
    }));

  const listRequest$ = refresh$
    .startWith(`initial`)
    .map(_ => ({
      url: `${usersAPIPath}?since=${Math.round(Math.random()*500)}`,
      key: `users`,
    }));

  const dom$ = userResponse$.map(res => h('div', JSON.stringify(res)));

  return {
    DOM: dom$,
    HTTP: listRequest$.merge(userRequest$),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it still seems kind of magic to me though. Do I understand correctly that `userRequest$` just waits for `listResponse$` to emit anything and then just do what’s next in chain?

Comment: Correct. It maps an event from `listResponse$` to a new request.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again, I really like cycle.js and will continue to dig into it.

Comment: I finally figured out the cyclejs HTTP driver used here is the @cycle/fetch driver: https://github.com/cyclejs/cycle-fetch-driver

Answer (score 0):

Because inquiring minds want to know...here's a complete working example:

```
import Cycle from '@cycle/rx-run';
import {div, button, makeDOMDriver} from '@cycle/dom';
import {makeFetchDriver} from '@cycle/fetch';
import R from 'ramda'

function main({DOM, HTTP}) {

  const usersAPIPath = 'https://api.github.com/users';
  const refresh$ = DOM.select('button').events('click');

  const userResponse$ = getJSON({ key: 'user' }, HTTP);
  const listResponse$ = getJSON({ key: 'users' }, HTTP);

  const userRequest$ = listResponse$
    .map(users => ({
      url: R.prop('url', R.head(users)),
      key: 'user',
    }));

  const listRequest$ = refresh$
    .startWith('initial')
    .map(_ => ({
      url: `${usersAPIPath}?since=${Math.round(Math.random()*500)}`,
      key: 'users',
    }));

  const dom$ = userResponse$.map(res => div([
    button('Refresh'),
    div(JSON.stringify(res))
  ]));

  return {
    DOM: dom$,
    HTTP: listRequest$.merge(userRequest$)
  };

  function getJSON(by, requests$) {
    return requests$.byKey(by.key)
      .mergeAll()
      .flatMap(res => res.json());
  }
}

Cycle.run(main, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#main-container'),
  HTTP: makeFetchDriver()
});
```

It took me a while to figure out `HTTP` was the [`@cycle/fetch`](https://github.com/cyclejs/cycle-fetch-driver) driver, and NOT the [`@cycle/http`](https://github.com/cyclejs/http) driver. Next, a bit of searching turned the [`ramda`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda) npm library providing `prop` and `head` methods.